# Promotional Odwalla bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

My son won this bike at work, and never got a chance to use it before moving for a job. He has asked me to sell it but I don't know anything about it or how much it's worth.  Any help would be appreciated[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a fairly generic beach cruiser to me.  The wide saddle (seat) implies a comfort bike.

There's no suspension, but the tyres (tires) look fairly wide so it should roll over most street things without a problem.

I cannot see any brakes - either they're not installed yet, or it may be a coaster brake in the rear wheel.  There are no disk brake lugs on the front fork, so it has to be rim brakes.

Its either a single speed/fixed speed, or there might be a internally-geared hub in the middle of the rear wheel.

Full mudguards (fenders) would mean this is fine to ride on wet days.

The only odd thing I can see is the metal disks in the middle of the rear wheel - they may be packing protectors for the mechanicals back there, or they may be some part of the chaincase protection.

---

We don't do pricing or valuations here, but its a new bike.  You could assemble it and ride it yourself, or list it on ebay/CL for a low start.  It is worth whatever someone is prepared to pay for it.

Or you could keep it for the grandchildren :-P